# Android Activity Instance in Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity, instance

In my android project I have the MainActivity and a Service. How can I get the activity's instance in my service?

Comment: Hi Rai, why do you want to have a reference to your activity from service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to? Are you trying to communicate between the Service and the Activity? If so, then getting the Activity object in the Service is probably not the way you want to go.

An Activity fits into the MVC model as a combination View/Controller. A Service is a Controller. To pass information between them, you need to update the Model, which can be SharedPreferences, a broadcast Intent, a content provider, and so forth. What you *shouldn't* do is assume that various components in your app are all part of a monolithic "whole". An Android app is a loose connection of individual pieces that should communicate with each other using Android constructs rather than variables, and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an appropriate approach. Instead, send messages to the activity, if it exists, to do things. Use `LocalBroadcastManager`, or a third-party message bus like Square's [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), or a `Messenger`, or something to pass messages from the service to the activity.